# What is the correct way to set Parsley.js global defaults in version 2.4.x

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I searched and couldn't find the answer in the Parsley documentation.

As of version 2.4.x, is this correct way to set parsley global default options?

```
<script src="Parsley-2.4.3/dist/parsley.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>    
//set options after parsley.min.js for v2.4.x?
$.extend(window.Parsley.options, {
  excluded: 'input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset], .search, .ignore',
  triggerAfterFailure: 'input change blur',
  errorsContainer: function (element) {}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, My example above is correct.